# Is the chat down right now?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I cannot access the chat right now. On Opera it was trying to get me to download some random file. On firefox it is saying that it is redirecting in a way that will never complete or something.

After a while refreshing with opera for a while it said it blocked me. But now its not doing it any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a DNS problem with chat (was resolving to NY instead of OR). Should be fixed now.